# How to embed ejs loop in parent element

Tags: html, css, express, ejs

I have this `ejs` template code that loops through array of objects and returns a page with number of div elements with bootstrap `class="card"`.

```
<div class="container">
<% blogs.forEach(function(blog){ %>
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="<%= blog.image %>">
        <div class="card-body"></div>
            <h3 class="card-title"><%= blog.title %></h3>
            <p><%= blog.created %></p>
            <p class="card-text"><%= blog.content.substring(0, 100) %></p>
            <a href="/blogs/<%= blog._id %>">read more...</a>
        </div>
    </div>
<% }); %>
</div>
```

But it only returns one `div.card` inside `div.container`, and the rest of them outside, after `div.container`.
How do I put all of div.card inside div.container?

Comment: The problem is probably in this line `<div class="card-body"></div>` you should remove `</div>` closing tag because you already have it on line 10. That is what is screwing up your loop.

Comment: thx... I should probably wear glasses :)  ...and remove this stupid question :)

Comment: Maybe vote up my comment before that ;)

Comment: You really did help me, so I'll be glad to vote you up. But I'm new to this stuff and this is my first question (which I'm not so proud of :), and I don't see where can I do this?

Comment: Don't worry about it :) Glad I could help. Just hover over the left side of my comment and then the up arrow should appear, and just click on it to mark it as helpful.

Comment: Just found out that I can't vote because i don't have enough reputation points.  Sorry :)

Comment: Hehehe :) Stack Overflow can be tricky like that. Never mind. Have a nice day ;)